# How can we control if a variable exists or not in Java?

Tags: java, swing, controls, jbutton, local-variables

In Java how can we control if a variable was already created or not ?
For example, I want to create a button with the variable name `kutu` but if there already is a button with the variable name `kutu` I don't want to create it.

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

           JButton kutu=new JButton("my box");
           kutu.setBounds(480, 620,120, 50);add(kutu);
           remove(button1);
           revalidate();
           repaint();
       }});
```

This is the code. There are 24 buttons (all of them have same action) and if the user clicks 2 or more buttons I dont want to create `JButton kutu` because `kutu` is already created in first click.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Make it clearer

Comment: you are right it is variable not object

Comment: You put your buttons in a Container object, then [iterate over the elements of your container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents()) and see if there is a button there with your name already.

Comment: `JButton a = new JButton("my box"); JButton b = new JButton("my box"); add(a); add(b);` Is this what you mean by creating (or adding) an object that already exists? Different variables, same objects?

Comment: i created int a and i will create int b if a is already created.how can i control a?

Comment: Please edit your question and re-write it more clearly. If you are not talking about variables, fix the title.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels In the question the user clearly says the intention is to find out if a button with the "same name" already exists. That **make sense** to me.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo: chit, he's creating his variable in a local scope. Out of the scope, the variable name doesn't even exist.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You've already clearly stated that point. My comment is in other direction. If what the user actually meant is the name of the button, not the name of the variable. It is clear the user is confused. I am simply interpreting what s/he might have meant in a way would make sense to me. I rest my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is use a class field not a local variable. This way you can test if an object has been created and assigned to the class field before, and if not, create a new object and assign it to the variable:

```
public class MyClass {
  private JButton kutu = null;

  // in some action listener:
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // only create this JButton if the variable has not
    // been assigned a JButton object
    if (kutu == null) {
      kutu = new JButton("Some Text");

      // ... etc
    }
  }
```

---

As an aside, you don't want to use null layouts and `setBounds(...)`. While initially this might seem the best and easiest way to create complex GUI's, if you program with Swing for any length of time, you'll come to find out that using null layouts puts your program into a straight jacket, making it very rigid, and very difficult to enhance. It also makes a GUI that looks good on one platform only.

Comment: @user3368157: you're welcome. Thank you for clarifying your question for us.